# MapServer WMS with inline Element export is not exported correctly in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapserver

I have a WMS service from MapServer 7.0.4 with a trademark as POINT inline Feature in the bottom corner defined with image coordinates. Therefore, it is always in the same place.

As soon as I export the map with print composer, due to the tiling, depending on the resolution, the trademark is displayed several times.

The problem is present from QGIS 2.1.4 - 3.0.2.

Has someone an idea how to solve this?

[image]
This is the MapServer code for the Trademark

---

[image]
This is the prind composer window.

---

[image]
This is the exported Raster image (600dpi)